# Background is only as wide as view-port

Tags: html, css, width

Annoying problem!

When I zoom-in on my view-port window (happens in Firefox, chrome) and then scroll horizontally to the right, my background images are clipped

the images best depicts what's happening:

**zoom in**

[image: zoom in] - image is only as wide as view-port

**zoom way out - problem doesn't occur**

[image: zoom out - problem gone]

Here are some sections from my css which might be relevant:

```
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}
body{ width: 100%; }
header#header { width: 100%; }
header#header #background-image {
  height: 150px;
  background: url(/images/header/silhouette.png) repeat-x;
}
```

This happens with and without cssgradients applied too - really stumped here

Comment: did you try to set to #background-image 100% width too?

Comment: I've never seen `header` or things like `figcaption` be elements in HTML like `body` or `div`... does that even work correctly? its not a class or id reference, Maybe I missed something tho. I've just never seen that done in CSS styles

Comment: Found the solution, now you need to go and test it. :) Read my answer. :)

Comment: @Jakub : He is attempting to use HTML5 google this "html5 w3schools" and you get http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_reference.asp

Comment: @steweb - you almost had it, I just had to set a min-width on the body  - thanks to everyone for your suggestions, especially mr @JamesM-SiteGen who gave me some nice tips but unfortunately deleted them before I could thank him

Comment: @stephenmurdoch there is the post I deleted, I merged it with my other answer.

Comment: @stephenmurdoch You should update the first image under the whole post as what you are getting now somewhat like `**Edit:**\n\n<img...>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fix for this is to set min-width on the body:

```
body{ width:100%;min-width: 1002px; }
```

This fixes problem on all browsers that I have as well as iphone (according to [iphonetester](http://iphonetester.com/) although I realise it's probably best to add some media queries now to really give the best solution to handheld users

Comment: :) I included that in my updated answer :) It also covers another method, Both work, and it has several tips and tricls.

Comment: legendary answer, thank you!  Does anyone know why it's "1002px" though?

Comment: @Webbo, I just used that figure because it worked with my screen :) YMMV

Comment: @stephenmurdoch Worked with mine too, bizarre coincidence!